# Check Box Node Tree , Custom Renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtree, cellrenderer

I have a custom checkbox node tree .
The structure is like this .

[image]

You can notice that the subtree is drawn from the check box node tree.

And what i need is ,

[image]

The sub tree must be drawn under the folder icon and not the check box.

Please guide me on this regard .

Comment: can you please post code how did you create JTree structure,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a custom `TreeCellRenderer`? Just indent it, i.e. add padding to the left which has the width of the folder icon. If you are not using a custom `TreeCellRenderer`: That is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Add `One` as a leaf (like `Two` and `Three`).  The tree does not make sense otherwise.

Comment: please to check her/his history, there is about definitions for Nodes,

Comment: @mKorbel  Ah-ha, I'd even seen and up-voted your two replies!  It's all coming back to me..

Comment: @Andrew : This actually makes sense.